# How can we alert when EFS is unmounted for Linux EC2 servers?

Tags: shell-script, amazon-ec2, unmounting

I am using below script in cron job to get alert whenever EFS got unmounted.

But its not alerting me when the EFS is unmounted.

```
#!/bin/bash
Hostname=$(hostname)
##email subject
subject="EFS is unmounted"
## sending mail to
to="xxxxx@gmail.com"
## send carbon copy to
also_to="xxxxx@gmail.com"

## Check if EFS is mounted or not
efscommenpart=$(df -kh | grep amazonaws.com | cut -d "." -f4)

## If EFS is unmounted
if [[ "$efscommenpart" -ne amazonaws  ]]

then

        echo -e "EFS is not mounted" | mailx -s "$subject" -r "$Hostname" -c "$to" "$also_to"
fi
```

Can anyone suggest me where am i doing mistake?

This is urgent...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [bash scripting guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) will tell you, `-ne` does integer comparison. To compare strings, you'll need to use the `!=` operator instead.

Example:

```
$ var=empty
$ if [[ $var != "amazonews" ]]; then echo Send Email; else echo All Good; fi
Send Email

$ var=amazonews
$ if [[ $var != "amazonews" ]]; then echo Send Email; else echo All Good; fi
All Good
```

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel It was helpful.